# How to copy files from sub folder only using cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder structure like:

```
-MainDir
  -f0
   -f0
    -f0
     -a.txt
     -b.txt
     -c.txt
  -f1
   -f1
    -f1
     -aa.txt
     -bb.txt
     -cc.txt
```

If you see above my files are in 3rd folder in terms of hierarchy. Now my requirement is to be able to copy only the main folder and it's files to another location. For example: output for above structure should be as following:

```
-MainDir
   -f0
    -a.txt
    -b.txt
    -c.txt
   -f1
    -aa.txt
    -bb.txt
    -cc.txt
```

but when I try using XCOPY, all the folders get copied as it is. So I am trying to figure out a way to achieve my target folder structure as shown above

Comment: While still included in Windows 10, `Xcopy` has been deprecated in favor of [Robocopy](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).

Comment: Can Robocpy achieve what I am trying to achieve here. Is yes, could you please share an example?

Comment: Do the sub-folders in a branch really have the same name (`f0\f0\f0`)?

Comment: yes @aschipfl. That's how they are structured on data sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will loop the directories under main, find all files, and put them all in the top most sub directory in destination as you're looking for:

CMD Script:

```
@(SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_MainDir=C:\Main\Dir"
  SET "_DestDir=%Temp%\Destination\Main\Dir"
)

FOR /D %%A in (
  %_MainDir%\*
) DO (
  IF NOT EXIST "%_DestDir%\%%~nxA" MD "%_DestDir%\%%~nxA"
  FOR /F %%a IN ('
    DIR /A-D /S /B "%%~fA\*"
  ') DO (
    ECHO Copying: "%%~fa"
    ECHO To: "%_DestDir%\%%~nxA\%%~nxa"
    COPY /B /V /Y "%%~fa" "%_DestDir%\%%~nxA\%%~nxa"
  )
)
```

Comment: This is creating the first folder f0, but none of the files (a.txt, b.txt...) got copied. As I mentioned files are under 3rd level of f0 folder, so basically I am trying to get rid of first two redundant folders and copy rest of the structure along with files. Also, there are multiple folder structures like these, like f0, f1,...etc.

Comment: Actually I think Copying shouldn't be there as I am seeing error that Copying is an unrecognized command.

Comment: It was a typo, I have modified the code to fix that issue.

Comment: @Compo  Thanks for catching that Compo.

Comment: @vsingh It was a typo, Compo Corrected the code, I just let off the `echo` from a couple lines that are just there to print out the status for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite easy task using [`xcopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) together with a [`for /D` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html), given that the three sub-directories in each hierarchy branch are equally named (like `f0\f0\f0` and `f1\f1\f1`):

```cmd
rem // Loop through immediate sub-sirectories of main directory:
for /D %%I in ("D:\MainDir\*") do (
    rem /* Build path to files into second sub-directory (though there are no files);
    rem    the third sub-directory and its contents is regarded due to the `/S` option;
    rem    the copy destination directory then receives the whole contents of the
    rem    second source sub-directory, including the third source sub-directory: */
    xcopy /S /I "%%~I\%%~nxI\*.*" "D:\CopyDir"
)
```

Comment: I misstated the requirement. I took another look at the structure. Main directory has f0,f1.....fn folders. Each of those folders have sub folders and files. Now we need to copy it to destination location so that all the files from sub folders are consolidated. So target directory would have only the key 1st level folders, like f0, f1, f2....fn. all the files from underlying folders will be consolidated and kept under these key folders.

Comment: Well, could there occur any file name collisions then? I mean, a file in the first level folder has got the same name as a file in a sub-(sub-)directory?

Comment: yeah, i checked on that and there won't be any duplicate file names for the parent level folder and sub folders.

Comment: I have found that you asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58190999) to cover the updated requirements, which I moved a part of this answer to as it is more suitable there...