# Copy first level folder and consolidate all the files within subfolders

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have multiple folders s1,s2.....sn on main directory. Each of these folders have multiple sub folders, folders within folders and then files. Structure kind of looks like:

mainDir

```
  -s1
       -f1
         -c1
           -a.txt
           -b.txt
         -c2
           -m.txt
           -n.txt
       -f2
         -c1
           -aaa.txt
           -bbb.txt
         -c2
           -mmm.txt
           -nnn.txt
     -s2
       -f1
         -c1
           -a.txt
           -b.txt
         -c2
           -m.txt
           -n.txt
       -f2
         -c1
           -aaa.txt
           -bbb.txt
         -c2
           -mmm.txt
           -nnn.txt
     -s3 ..................
```

Now we need to get rid of all subfolders and keep only . the first level folders and all the underlying files. So final destination should like:

```
DestDirectory
      -s1
        -a.txt
        -b.txt
        -m.txt
        -n.txt
        -aaa.txt
        -bbb.txt
        .....so on
      -s2
        -a.txt
        -b.txt
        -m.txt
        -n.txt
        -aaa.txt
        -bbb.txt
        .....so on
```

Comment: You should please take the [tour] and read [ask], then you will find out that you need to put some effort in solving your task on your own and include a [mcve] of your coding attempts; otherwise, this is nothing but a script request, which is clearly off-topic here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [`for /D` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) to iterate the first-level sub-directories, then a nested [`for /R` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) to iterate through all files in the immediate sub-directories, then use [`copy`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) to copy each file individually in order to achieve the flat destination directory hierarchy. To avoid file name collisions (meaning that files with the same name appear in different source sub-directory hierarchy levels), an `if exist` directive can be used. So here is the code:

```cmd
rem // Loop through immediate sub-sirectories of main directory:
for /D %%I in ("D:\MainDir\*") do (
    rem // Temporarily change to the currently iterated sub-directory:
    pushd "%%~I" && (
        rem // Iterate through all files in the current directory recusrively:
        for /R %%J in ("*.*") do (
            rem /* Create destination directory if necessary, which is named like
            rem    the current directory, that is the first source sub-directory: */
            2> nul md "D:\CopyDir\%%~nxI"
            rem // Temporarily change to the destination directory:
            pushd "D:\CopyDir\%%~nxI" && (
                rem // Check for potential file name collisions:
                if not exist "%%~nxJ" (
                    rem // No collision, hence copy current file:
                    copy "%%~J" "%%~nxJ"
                ) else (
                    rem // Collision, so return an error message:
                    >&2 echo ERROR: "%%~nxI\%%~nxJ" already exists!
                )
                rem // Return from destination directory:
                popd
            )
        )
        rem // Return from currently iterated source sub-directory:
        popd
    )
)
```

Comment: *Note:* This answer has been moved from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58187649/2)...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to find out if there would be any filename collisions occur when moving files from multiple directories into a single directory.

=== Find-DupeFilenames.ps1

```
$h = @{}

Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($h.ContainsKey($_.Name)) {
            "Name conflict {0} is in both {1} and {2}" -f @($_.Name, $h[$_.Name], $_.DirectoryName)
        } else {
            $h.Add($_.Name, $_.DirectoryName)
        }
    }
```

If you need to run this from a cmd.exe shell prompt, use this to get a quick count.

```
CD /D C:\mainDir
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(C:\src\Find-DupeFilenames.ps1 | Measure-Object).Count"
```

Use this to list all conflicted filenames.

```
CD /D C:\mainDir
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ".\Find-DupeFilenames.bat"
```

Answer (score 0):

How is this any different from your Previous question? [How to copy files from sub folder only using cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173730/how-to-copy-files-from-sub-folder-only-using-cmd/58174103#58174103)

Perhaps in your previous Q you had all same-named folders?

The Code below should also work for the differently named folders as you described here.

CMD Script:

```
@(SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_MainDir=C:\Main\Dir"
  SET "_DestDir=%Temp%\Destination\Main\Dir"
)

FOR /D %%A in (
  %_MainDir%\*
) DO (
  IF NOT EXIST "%_DestDir%\%%~nxA" MD "%_DestDir%\%%~nxA"
  FOR /F %%a IN ('
    DIR /A-D /S /B "%%~fA\*"
  ') DO (
    ECHO Copying: "%%~fa"
    ECHO To: "%_DestDir%\%%~nxA\%%~nxa"
    COPY /B /V /Y "%%~fa" "%_DestDir%\%%~nxA\%%~nxa"
  )
)
```

Comment: I actually had a different problem statement in that question and I didn't want to change anything in the question there which could have confused others. So I have created new questions to keep these two problem statements separately.